# PHP/mySQL - INSERT INTO not working but also no error

Tags: php, sql

one specific php/mydql command is not working. the sql will not be executed, nor do I get an error message. The sql command executed by HEIDI SQL gives me no error. Query before this command are executed correct. Only this one specific isn't working. I wrote it done one by one as the others which worked perfect before. Heres the code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,password,email) VALUES(?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($username, $hash, $email));
```

The connection.php file code:

```
global $conn; 
$config = [
$dbname = "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=starwardb;",
$login = "root",
$password = ""
];
try {
$conn = new PDO(...$config);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo "ERROR: " . $ex;
}
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: I see no error handling

Comment: This looks like PDO? Couple of things to check and do: Enable PHP error-reporting, set PDO to throw exceptions so any errors can't be ignored, and check that your connection is valid.

Comment: @Qirel could even be mysqli (or connection), who really knows. Edit: yep, it's PDO alright. OP had the connection in a comment below but deleted it.

Comment: It could be, but we don't know ;) Which is why I asked, "*This looks like PDO?*" ;-)

Comment: Add `$conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`  after connecting - that way you can't ignore any errors in the query, if you just enable error-reporting and check your logs.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Unpacking of arrays, introduced in PHP 5.6 - http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat

Comment: @Qirel thanks for that info

Comment: take a look here for better understanding of pdo 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/introduction-php-data-objects/

Comment: `UPDATE: SOLVED` is not how a question should be updated. Please add the answer to the `Answer` section, or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

> The mistake was, that the hashing of the password extends the string. The Database length of the password was by 50. I have increased it to 64 and now it works fine.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45147068/3